# Libgdx Robovm iOS icons with Gradle

Tags: ios, icons, libgdx, robovm

I cant find anywhere on the internet on how to add icons for iOS with the Gradle libgdx how will I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Create a folder (eg. `resources`) under the root of RoboVM project (usually `your-project-ios`)
- Put your icons in that folder (make sure your icons have valid names according to guidelines, but you can generate them with lot of online tools, for example: [http://makeappicon.com](http://makeappicon.com/))
- Edit your `robovm.xml` file and add these lines into the resources:

```xml
<resource>
    <directory>resources</directory>
</resource>
```

You will get something similar to this:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>../android/assets</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**</include>
        </includes>
        <skipPngCrush>true</skipPngCrush>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

- Edit your `Info.plist.xml` file and add these lines at the end (before `</dict></plist>`)

```xml
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon</string>
            <string>Icon-72</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

[Source](https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/152)